# Stuck on the login screen

Tags: login, xfce, xubuntu

I installed xubuntu DE on my machine and when I rebooted, my ubuntu got stucked on the login screen.
Even the command to bring up the terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is not working and everytime I enter the password, it prompts me to enter it again, and this loop continues... 
I installed xubuntu using the command:

```
$ sudo apt install xfce4
```

My PC is HP 20-c102il (AIO PC) with 8GB RAM and Intel Celeron J3060 Dual Core Processor clocked on 1.68GHz and I use Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Desktop.

Comment: Please tell us more about the computer and original operating system: 1. Computer brand name and model? Original operating system: version 20.04 LTS? Original desktop environment? (or maybe server without graphical desktop)? -- This information will help us help you.

Comment: Did you install a display manager for example LightDM ? The inability to log in on the command line could be due to a wrong keyboard layout on startup.

Comment: @sudodus The info is added to the question. Kindly check...

Comment: @Anonymous I installed gdm3 as my display manager when prompted. And kindly tell what's the solution to a wrong keyboard layout and how to bring up the terminal on the login screen to fix the issue.

Comment: Sounds familiar, I have been running into something similar thing on a 16.04 Lubuntu VM. The login screen doesn't indicate a bad username/password, right, it just displays the login screen again?

Comment: Run `systemctl status gdm3` and see if the service is started **and** enabled. Probably not. Run `systemctl start gdm3` first. If it works then you can type `systemctl enable gdm3` so that the service will automatically start at boot.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Desktop, and into that system installed an extra desktop environment `xfce4`? It might work better with the whole `xubuntu-desktop`. This kind of operation may or may not work (with two desktop environments in the same operating system). But first: Did the Ubuntu Desktop (I think Gnome) work as it should, or was there some problem?

Comment: @sudodus Actually I was using two DEs already - KDE Plasma and Gnome and when I tried to install the xfce4 environment, this problem occurred... so there are 3 DEs on the same OS (18.04.4 LTS) in total.

Comment: @cherdt Exactly! I'm stuck in a login loop...

Comment: i would try to install the whole `xubuntu-desktop`. It is a meta package (containing xfce4 plus a lot of other packages and tweaks) and I think it will increase the chances that your system will work again. But first - backup your system or at least all the files, that you cannot afford to lose - in the end it may turn out that the best solution is to reinstall the Ubuntu flavour that you want and get a clean desktop environment. It is better to have a second system, where you can test things. This could be 'dual boot' or 'triple boot', or it could be in a virtual machine.